# how to change background in chartjs and remove background lines?

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

How to change background color, and remove this lines, and how to cahnge some tex,

for example: text of point, when you hover on some point you get title and value of this.

[image]

my js

```
function creating_chart(get_wrapper,type_of_chart, labels_of_chart, data_of_charts, title_of_chart){
                var ctx = document.getElementById(get_wrapper).getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: type_of_chart,
                    data: {
                        labels: labels_of_chart,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: title_of_chart,
                            data: [2220, 19998, 55547, 55784, 999985], //data_of_charts
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(47, 152, 208, 0.2)',
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(19, 247, 228,1)',
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(19, 247, 228,1)',
                            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(19, 247, 228,1)',
                            pointBorderWidth: 5,
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero:true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
```

Comment: What do you mean by change some text? Like change text color or replace with something else?

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ I at least change the background, that is, remove the lines, and if you change the text, then this is when you point to the point, to show the dollar signs, and the metric of the sum on the left, to add there too!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **change background color**

use css to set background color for canvas *(chart)* element :

```
canvas {
   background-color: rgba(47, 152, 208, 0.1);
}
```

> **remove grid-lines**

set **`display`** property of gridLines to `false` for both x and y axis :

```
scales: {
   xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
         display: false
      }
   }],
   yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
         display: false
      }
   }]
}
```

> **change text of tooltip­*'s* label** *(add $ symbol)*

use a callback function for tooltips label, as such :

```
tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
      label: function(t, d) {
         var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
         var yLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index];
         return xLabel + ': $' + yLabel;
      }
   }
}
```

see a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/dvL86vjr/).

Comment: @GRUNT and you do not know how to remove the numbers on the left, the metric?

Comment: set `ticks: {display: false}` for y-axis.. see - https://jsfiddle.net/dvL86vjr/1/

Comment: @GRUNT you amazing)

Comment: @Grunt Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: This solution also hides the lines along the x and y axes. Setting `drawOnChartArea: false` may be preferable behavior, for many.